# python helper functions and return statements

Tags: python, sorting, tuples, return-value

The function below (sort_priority_0) sorts a list of numbers but prioritizes one group of numbers to come first. What is the purpose of the tuple in the return statement?

```
numbers = [8, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6]
group = {2, 3, 5, 7}

def sort_priority_0(values, group):
    def helper(x):
        if x in group:
            return 0, x
        return 1, x
    values.sort(key=helper)

python sort_priority_0.py 
[2, 3, 5, 7, 1, 4, 6, 8]
```

If I modify the function and removing the tuple, the sort is done in ascending order. Please explain why the behavior is so drastically different with and without the tuple in the return statement?

```
def sort_priority_1(values, group):
    def helper(x):
        if x in group:
            return x
        return x
    values.sort(key=helper)

python sort_priority.py 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: So you know what the `key` argument in the `.sort()` does?

Comment: @KlausD. Yes I’m just not clear on the purpose of the tuple in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `key` parameter in `sort` takes a function. You can think of it this way: if `key` is provided, then the input iterable will be sorted *as if `key` was applied to each element*.

`tuples` are sorted by their first element, then their second, and so on. In this case, the key function converts all elements in the iterable to be sorted into `tuples`, where the first element is 0 if the number is in the priority group, and 1 otherwise.

This means that, since `sort` is ascending by default, all priority numbers will come first, and they will internally be sorted in ascending order.

To illustrate, you can think of the process as having the following steps:

1. Start with `[8, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6]`
2. Apply `key` to get:

```
[(1, 8), (0, 3), (1, 1), (0, 2), (0, 5), (1, 4), (0, 7), (1, 6)]
```

3. Sort the result in ascending order to get:

```
[(0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 5), (0, 7), (1, 1), (1, 4), (1, 6), (1, 8)]
```

4. Take the corresponding elements of the original data (in this case, the second element of the `tuple`, though because this is index-based the original elements need not be recoverable from the output of the key function):

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 1, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `helper` function in `sort_priority_0` ensures that first the elements in the group are sorted in an ascending order, and then the remaining elements are sorted in an ascending order, as you can observe below.

```
print(sort_priority_0(numbers,{2, 3, 5, 7}))
#[2, 3, 5, 7, 1, 4, 6, 8]
print(sort_priority_0(numbers,{4, 2, 5, 8}))
#[2, 4, 5, 8, 1, 3, 6, 7]
print(sort_priority_0(numbers,{6, 4, 5, 1}))
#[1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 7, 8]
```

Returning `0,x` for the elements in the group makes sure that those elements are pushed to the front of the list while sorting, and the remaining are pushed in the later half of the list via `1,x`, and then sorted in an ascending order, since sorting happens on `0` and `1`, and then within the numbers